# Instagram like photo editing feature

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have seen apps like `Instagram` and many more, could take a photo and change the colour of the image, as in fade, brightness, gray-scale, and various image processing effects added to it.

I need to try this out, so can someone help me find a good tutorial, to begin with.

For now, my program could take the picture from the camera, but I am unable to process the image as shown on Instagram.

Comment: Try this CoreImage tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5

Comment: The official CoreImage programming guide can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html

Comment: Oh is it only for iOS 5 ? I want it on iOS4 too

Comment: For the gray-scale and color scheme changes, you can use Core Image (filters), as the others have said. For the "fade" effect, you can change the alpha property of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open source image filter library that might help: https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr